# fire fox config for web sampler (jmeter) is not working

Tags: performance, firefox, jmeter

Please help. My web driver sampler for jmeter is not working. Im using firefox config.

```
2019-07-12 20:55:38,913 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:843) ~[guava-28.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:125) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:43) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:168) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:346) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:99) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:22) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994) [jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977) [jorphan.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

> The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

You need to:

1. Download [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
2. Define `webdriver.gecko.driver` [Java system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html). In case of JMeter it can be done in 2 ways:

   - pass the location of the geckodriver binary via `-D` command-line argument:

     ```
     jmeter -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/path/to/geckodriver.binary
     ```
   - or if you want to make the change permanent - add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

     ```
     webdriver.gecko.driver=/path/to/geckodriver.binary
     ```

     JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

References:

- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)